# Android RC2 Encryption

Tags: android, encryption, encryption-symmetric, rc2-cipher

I'm working on making an Android client for a fairly old webservice.  The webservice requires that I encrypt some of the data I send to it in RC2 style.  I'm having trouble getting anything (Cipher, KeyFactory, KeyGenerator, etc.) to even have an RC2 implementation available.

I can't change the webservice so I'm stuck with the RC2 encryption (I know it's older and not really preferred).

Is there any implementation I can use in java/android libraries?  I would prefer to use built in components but would be willing to use a third party library if I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bouncy Castle is a pretty save bet. You may want to extract the RC2 code from the bouncy lightweight API and put it straight in your code base to safe on resources. Bouncy Castle is *very* liberally licensed...